# SonataAdminBundle "sonata_type_translatable_choice" field type

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm struggling with the "sonata_type_translatable_choice" field type.

PageAdmin.php :

```
  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper
      ->with('page.title', ['class' => 'col-md-12'])
        ->add('name', null, ['label' => 'page.field.name'])
        ->add('code', null, ['label' => 'page.field.code'])
        ->add('content', 'ckeditor', ['label' => 'page.field.content'])
        ->add('status', 'sonata_type_translatable_choice', [
          'choices' => Page::$statuses,
          'catalogue' => 'admin',
          'label' => 'page.field.status'
        ])
      ->end()
    ;
  }
```

Page.php :

```
  public static $statuses = array(
    self::STATUS_HIDDEN => 'page.status.hidden',
    self::STATUS_OFFLINE => 'page.status.offline',
    self::STATUS_DRAFT => 'page.status.draft',
    self::STATUS_ONLINE => 'page.status.online'
  );
```

admin.en.yml :

```
page:
    status:
        hidden: hidden
        offline: offline
        draft: draft
        online: online
```

The form is displaying the select field with the values : "page.status.hidden" instead of "hidden" located in my .yml file.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: First: After adding new translation file you need to clear cache for current env. Second: check if translation is loaded in Symfony - try to render it on some template.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache and this is not working. My translation file is loaded, all others translations works.

Comment: The Symfony Profiler tool (available in dev mode if you didn't disable it) contains a tab listing all missing translations and all their expected domains. It might help you. The command `app/console debug:translation` might also be a lead.

Comment: Thank you @Zephyr, I already checked out the debug:translation and the translation appear.

Comment: What translation domain does it use? Had that matched the missing translations displayed by the profiler? In Symfony, translations are grouped by domain, this is an importand concept to understand here.

Comment: Alright I found it. Those translations called the translation domain "messages" and not "admin" despite of what I put in the catalogue field. How can I set those translations into the translation domain "admin" ?